# How to replace string characters that are not in a reference list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have a reference string on which the allowed characters are listed. Then I also have input strings, from which not allowed characters should be replaced with a fixed character, in this example "0".

I can use filter but it removes the characters altogether, does not offer a replacement. Please note that it is not about being alphanumerical, there are ALLOWED non-alphanumerical characters and there are not allowed alphanumerical characters, referenceStr happens to be arbitrary.

```
var referenceStr = "abcdefg"
var inputStr = "abcqwyzt"
inputStr = inputStr.filter{it in referenceStr}
```

This yields:

```
"abc"
```

But I need:

```
"abc00000"
```

I also considered replace but it looks more like when you have a complete reference list of characters that are NOT allowed. My case is the other way around.

Comment: Quick [solution](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS42LjIxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGtvdGxpbi5tYXRoLnNpblxuaW1wb3J0IGtvdGxpbi5tYXRoLnJvdW5kVG9JbnRcbmltcG9ydCBqYXZhLnV0aWwuQ29sbGVjdGlvbnNcblxuZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgdmFsIHJlZmVyZW5jZVN0ciA9IFwiYWJjZGVmZ1wiXG4gICAgdmFsIGlucHV0U3RyID0gXCJhYmNxd3l6dFwiXG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbihpbnB1dFN0ci5tYXAgeyBpZiAoaXQgaW4gcmVmZXJlbmNlU3RyKSBpdCBlbHNlIFwiMFwiIH0uam9pblRvU3RyaW5nKFwiXCIpKVxufSJ9).

Comment: Exactly what wanted! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Alternative quick solution: `inputStr.replace("[^$referenceStr]".toRegex(), "0")` (caveat: it only works with restrictions, e.g. referenceStr must not contain "]")

Comment: @uğur-dinç Are you sure? This solution replace characters on current iteration. For example if we have `val referenceStr = "zbcdefg"`  the result will be `0bc000z0`, It is correct approach for solving you issue?

Comment: @Sky yes exactly :) That was great help thanks a lot.

Comment: @k314159 your solution also works equally well. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look to another [solution](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)

Comment: @Sky the second solution takes all the allowed characters at the beginning and adds 0s to the and, this is not quite what I would require but could be helpful for others needing it. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Sky would you mind if I accepted posted answer below, which is very similar to your solution as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
val referenceStr = "abcd][efg"
val replacementChar = '0'
val inputStr = "abcqwyzt[]"
```

You can do this with a regex `[^<referenceStr>]`, where `<referenceStr>` should be replaced with `referenceStr`:

```
val result = inputStr.replace("[^${Regex.escape(referenceStr)}]".toRegex(), replacementChar.toString())
println(result)
```

Note that `Regex.escape` is used to make sure that the characters in `referenceStr` are all interpreted literally.

Alternatively, use `map`:

```
val result = inputStr.map {
    if (it !in referenceStr) replacementChar else it
}.joinToString(separator = "")
```

In the lambda decide whether the current char "`it`" should be transformed to `replacementChar`, or itself. `map` creates a `List<Char>`, so you need to use `joinToString` to make the result a `String` again.

Comment: Is it just me or does the Kotlin stdlib seem a bit inconsistent that `String.filter` returns `String`, but `String.map` returns `List`?

Comment: @k314159 Note that this is using `CharSequence.map` and `String.filter`. `String.map` doesn't actually exist. But it is a bit inconsistent, isn't it? I think there should be a `String.map` extension that returns a `String` too.